# org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.ServerContainer cannot be cast to org.apache.tom cat.websocket.server.WsServerContaine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jetty

```
    2018-08-15 16:05:57.353:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6a400542{/,file:/o
    pt/meituan/fd/apps/fd-crm/webroot/,STARTING}
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.ServerContainer cannot be cast to org.apache.tom
    cat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.init(WsFilter.java:40)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:138)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:852)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1345)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1338)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:501)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbsConnection Reset By PeertractHandler.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            at com.sankuai.mms.boot.AbstractBootstrap.start(AbstractBootstrap.java:139)
            at com.sankuai.mms.boot.AbstractBootstrap.boot(AbstractBootstrap.java:66)
            at com.sankuai.mms.boot.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:28)
    2018-08-15 16:05:57.355:INFO:oejs.AbstractNCSARequestLog:main: Opened /opt/logs/fd/fd-crm/fd-crm.request.log.2018-08-15
    2018-08-15 16:05:57.366:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@3e20116c{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8060}
    2018-08-15 16:05:57.366:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @154910ms
```

Run project, get this exception. Http response 503.  Only find in product environment. Develop or pre-realease(database is the same as prouct) environment is ok.
History code version can deploy success. The main change is import a myself jar with spring-boot 2.0.0.RELEASE.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.6.v20141205</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed code.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.ServerContainer 
    cannot be cast to 
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.init(WsFilter.java:40)
```

That says you have a tomcat dependency (the tomcat websocket server) attempting to initialize within Jetty.